# asp.net shows weird symbols

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string

I'm building one application in asp.net mvc 4, and I'm taking all information from a json with newtonsoft json.

Some strings on this json have weird symbols, ie: "MÃœller" should be "MÜller" and other cases.

I understand that is something relating with encoding, But how can I change this to show the exactly text in the string?

Comment: can you post the raw json you get before parsing it with json.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Save your markup/json file by clicking File -> Advanced Save Options
Save as Unicode (UTF-8 With Signature) - Codepage 65001

Comment: the json file isnt mine

Comment: Are you fetching it with ajax/jquery?  What do you set as content type? I.e: Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8